# Calculate matrix in excel containing 0 values based on column and row totals

Tags: excel, matrix, sum

I have a matrix with totals rows and totals columns as follow

[matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z79sz.jpg)

I need to take these totals and calculate a value for each column within each row as follow

[desired matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2swwS.jpg)

I have used the following formula

Row Total*Column Total/Overall Total

which assumes a no-zero value per each column and each row.
Any tip for this?
thank you!
Chiara

Comment: Add a if statement to check if each values are no-zero ?

Comment: There is something (probably quite a lot) you are not disclosing about your desired matrix. Why do cols A and E have a full set of values, whilst `F` has only 2. There are an infinite number of ways to populate a 14*7 matrix so that it sums to your given row and column totals, so what is it that is driving you to your desired solution as opposed to any other possibility?

Comment: The numbers correspond to different regions and the letters to numbers of fishing gears. So not all the regions have those fishing gears. I have tried to use if statement as follow: =IF(A1<>"", ((Total 1*Total A)/TotalTotal),"") but by doing this, i exclude those blank cells from the calculation which in turn wrongly estimate the numbers in each row and each column.